# Python (PyPy) times.to_universal() doesn't work on Alpine linux

Tags: python, time, alpine-linux, pypy

I have problem in Alpine linux container to use time convertor, it results in the same time regardless what `timezone` I specify. Comparing to my localhost Ubuntu, the result is different event with same `times` version.

`times==0.7` on both systems

On Alpine Docker container I installed `tzdata` and set timezone properly to CET as well as on localhost. It shows the same date/time to `date` command.

alpine-pypy:3.6-7-alpine3.9 container, root user

```
Python 3.6.1 (de061d87e39c7df4e436974096d7982c676a859d, Mar 25 2019, 18:43:49)
[PyPy 7.1.0-beta0 with GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``I might, but nobody respects me''
>>>> import times
>>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>> times.to_universal(datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124), 'CET')
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124)
>>>> times.to_universal(datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124), 'Japan')
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124)
>>>> times.to_universal(datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124))
    datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124)
```

On localhost Ubuntu 20.04, pypy3

```
Python 3.6.9 (7.3.2+dfsg-2~ppa1~ubuntu20.04, Sep 26 2020, 22:37:47)
[PyPy 7.3.2 with GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> import times;from datetime import datetime
>>>> times.to_universal(datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124), 'CET')
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 12, 50, 24, 124)
>>>> times.to_universal(datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124), 'Japan')
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 4, 50, 24, 124)
>>>> times.to_universal(datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124))
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 13, 50, 24, 124)
```

Dockerfile to reproduce

```
FROM jamiehewland/alpine-pypy:3.6-7-alpine3.9
#FROM python:3.7.9-alpine3.11

ENV TZ CET

RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
    && apk add bash libxml2-dev libxslt-dev build-base tzdata \
    && ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

RUN pip install times==0.7
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour with CPython instead of Pypy?

Comment: Yes, same results on python:3.7.9-alpine3.11.

Comment: In this kind of situation I would use `pdb` to step through the code of the `times` module, on both machines.  This should quickly find the difference.